# Is it possible to get the result of 2 queries in a single roundtrip with pg-promise?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am working on a serverless application (AWS), which means the machine running my code and the one running my database may be physically separated. So I have to make sure that individual API request don't generate too many roundtrips to the server.

So I was wondering, is it possible to execute multiple queries in a single round trip to the server and receive the response?

Something like this:

```
db.result("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE office=$1;DELETE FROM offices WHERE id=$1 RETURNING *",[office]);
```

So that both the employees and the office are returned seperately? If I run it the way it is now, only the office is returned.

Comment: You're mixing things up here. The machines that run the database and that run the query are *usually* physically separated. That has nothing to do with "serverless". And the number of round-trips you make makes no difference, at least nothing about your setup makes fewer round-trips inherently favorable. So... this seems to be an XY problem. You're actually worried about/trying to solve a different issue than the one you're talking about.

Comment: Well since its serverless, AWS handless provisioning of machines. So theres no guarantee that the db and logic share a machine. So I thought it only makes sense to minimize roundtrips since even on my home network my ping to my router is 5ms, which might be how long it takes to execute the query, doubling the processing time.  But I also don't have the experience to say that with certainty. So you are saying many round trips are nothing to worry about?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, but this is an issue that affects *any* application that accesses a DB server, and has nothing to do with AWS in particular. Before you prematurely optimize, you should measure it and make sure that it's actually the slow part of your setup. It might already be mitigated well enough by things like persistent connections and connection pooling, and the effect of bending over backwards in your app to save query round-trips might not be large enough.

Comment: yeah you're probably right about testing it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to execute multiple queries in a single round trip to the server and receive the response?

Yes, the library has method [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) for that:

```js
const [employees, offices] = await db.multi(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE office = $1; 
                          DELETE FROM offices WHERE id = $1 RETURNING *`, [office]);
```

Comment: it still only returns the results from the last query:  rows: [ { id: 1, name: 'Office A' } ],

Comment: @user2741831 Ops, I meant `multi`, not `many`, sorry about that; corrected now ;)

Comment: thanks this works. Quick question though, does this actually send a single request or is it purely syntactic sugar (split it apart in code and send 2 sequential requests)?  I ask because I know multiple requests doen't work natively in node-pg.

Comment: It's the former :) - single request.